# LuaScriptAction error: attempt to index global 'out1' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I have this first script:

```
 out1 = io.popen("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php /var/www/knxweb/attiva_allarme.php");
 out1:close();
```

This is the second one:

```
out = io.popen("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php /var/www/knxweb/camip.php");
value = string.match(out:read("*a"), "[0-9.]+");
out:close();

    if (value ~= nil) then
        finale = tonumber(value);
        set("detect_camip", finale);
    end;
```

The first script give me this error:
`ERROR Action : LuaScriptAction error: [string "out1 = io.popen("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php /var/..."]:1: attempt to index global 'out1' (a nil value)`.

The second gives this error:
`ERROR Action : LuaScriptAction error: Incorrect value for 'set'`

I've tried all I could think of, but to no avail.

Comment: Hello m.Sarto, Welcome to StackOverflow. As a general rule, we don't include statements such as "could you please help", if you're asking here, it's assumed you're asking for help.

Comment: The first case failed to return a resulting file handle so `out1` contained `nil` and you can't call `close` on `nil`. You should catch the error return value as well and do something with it. The `set` function doesn't like what you handed it. Without knowing what that `set` function **is** though we can't help more than that.